# Gulp and Babel: Error: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a project that I've set up using `gulp` and `babel`. Everything is working fine, except when I create a module and import it once it's converted from ES6 to ES6 it doesn't work. I get an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'hello.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
```

Here's my `gulpfile.babel.js`:

```
import gulp from "gulp";
import babel from "gulp-babel"
import concat from "gulp-concat"

const dirs = {
  src: "src",
  dest: "build"
}

gulp.task("build", () => {
  return gulp.src(dirs.src + "/**/*.js")
         .pipe(babel())
         .pipe(concat("build.js"))
         .pipe(gulp.dest(dirs.dest))
});

gulp.task("default", ["build"]);
```

During build everything is concatenated into one file. Under `src/` I have:

- app.js
- hellojs

**app.js**

```
import hello from './hello.js'
console.log(hello());
```

**hello.js**

```
export default () => {
    return 'Hey from hello.js';
};
```

And I run like so:

```
npm start
```

Which basically calls `node ./build/build.js`.

I think it's because it's concatenating the ES6 into ES5 and the `bundle.js` still contains the require for `hello.js`. It wont find it though because its concatenated. Is that possible?

Comment: hope you are running after, npm install. right?

Comment: There's no need for me to run `npm install`. I'm working on the development machine where I installed the packages using `npm i gulp gulp-babel gulp-concat --save`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is incorrect to concatenate two module files and expect the program to work properly, even when transpiled to ES5. Bundling involves more than concatenating the scripts: each module needs a closure for registering exports and resolving the contents of other modules.

You must instead use a bundling tool such as Browserify, Webpack or Rollup. Here's how one would bundle with Browserify (which in this case, it is easier to rely on the Babelify transform rather than `gulp-babel`):

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var babelify = require('babelify');

gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    return browserify({
         entries: './src/app.js'
        })
        .transform(babelify)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});
```

Comment: This solution does work. I just tried it out myself and saw the exact errors you did before applying this change.

Comment: I've only used Webpack and was under the impression it's a web application bundler - or at least more suited to. What are the solutions for non browser based application bundlers? Such as sysadmin, web scraper tools etc.

Comment: @adam-beck ... I forgot to build! My bad.

Comment: @BugHunterUK any of these bundlers should also be usable in Node.js applications, although it doesn't serve greater purpose than for browser-based applications, which take real advantage of keeping all source code in a single file.

Comment: Yep. These tools are module bundlers. They are very common on the web because that environment doesn't have native bundles. Whereas node does -- commonjs. You don't really need to concat a node project into a single file so it's less common to see these tools (browserify, webpack, etc) used for them.

Comment: @E_net4 That's a valid point. I hadn't considered that. It does seem a little pointless to bundle everything for non browser based applications because it serves no real benefit.

Comment: @adam-beck I agree too. It was a bad idea on my part.

Comment: Well, there you go. I hope that the answer helped, nevertheless.